# Engraving with Displacement maps

Tags: displacement, bump

I want to engrave a drawing into a mesh.

I UV unwrapped the mesh exported the UV layout and textured it.

[image]

Now I don't know how I can get it into the displacement of the material. I already changed the displacement do *Displacement Only* but when I plug the texture into the height of a *Bump Node* which is connected to the displacement everything goes to hell.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the "displacement" node, check screenshot below.
Please keep in mind that you'll need a mesh with many faces to see any results.

[image]

Feel free to share your original file here if this answer is not helping you:
https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Ohhh I completely forgot about this one it is exactly what I need... Thank you