# image to displacement maps

Tags: displacement

i have old coin pictures as pngs or jpegs i want to turn them in to a displacement map that i can get good height to get a good rendering result.

how can i do that?

i have tryied these steps but it did not help.

[How do I make a normal/displacement map when all I have is a photo?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/390/how-do-i-make-a-normal-displacement-map-when-all-i-have-is-a-photo)

Comment: how does you picture look like? Maybe try a software like CrazyBump

Comment: similar to this
https://kvmgm.ktb.gov.tr/Resim/91918,ankarasahtesikke01.png?0

crayzbump did not work somehow it quits when i load the picture

Comment: seems perfect for a bump map, what difficulty have you met? Do you need a fake displacement or a real displacement of your topology?

Comment: can you check this answer? https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/174124/88382

Comment: with the displacement node and the methods described at other blender.stackexchange page i could not get the high resolution i want. that the main problem accually.

Comment: original picture
https://www.cigold.com.tr/images/urunler/2-5-luk-Ziynet-Altin-Yeni-resim-2127.jpg
my sample
https://i.hizliresim.com/wZERKk.png

it is not that high resolution as you can see.

Comment: If you need a real displacement it's going to be a bit harder, my answer is just for fake 3D

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is still not clear to me if you want to **fake** the 3D effect or if you want to **really displace** the topology, for example for 3D print purpose.

I don't know if you can achieve an accurate **real** displacement just from a b&w photo, because for this purpose you will need a picture that will precisely use black for bottom surfaces, white for peak surfaces, and all the shades of grey inbetween respecting the heights of the object surfaces, which is rarely the case with most photos.

Here is what my attempt gave from you coin picture. I chose a coin that had a better chance to give a good result: no oblique shadows, and the dark areas can be interpreted as the the bottom surface, bright areas as the peaks. As you see it is not very satisfying:

[image]
[image]

So the following answer is not for real displacement, it's only to **fake** 3D with *Normal* or *Bump* maps, in that case it's much less important if the grey spectrum doesn't respect exactly the heights of the real object.

I gave it a bit of additional margin to make the mapping easy:

[image]

I created a normal map with CrazyBump (a bump would have worked as well, no big difference):

[image]

Then I unwrapped, mixed a *Diffuse* with a *Glossy*, plugged the original (extended) image in their *Color* inputs, plugged the *Normal* map into their *Normal* inputs:

[image]

Comment: hi did you just use blender for height maps?

Comment: what do you mean? To create the normal map I've imported the coin picture into CrzayBump and convert it into a normal map (I could have converted to a bump map and use a Bump node instead of a Normal map, it's almost the same). Height map and bump map means the same thing actually, it's a b&w picture used to give (or fake) 3D. Normal map are a bit different, it works with 3 colors.

Comment: Actually it is still not clear to me if you want to fake the 3D effect or if you want to really displace the topology, for example for 3D print purpose. In the latter case, you need very particular height map that are able to reproduce the real bumps of the object, otherwise you won't have any good result.

Comment: i want a real displacement not fake one. like this https://youtu.be/arvhK4tvYuY?t=830

fake displacement maps will cause problem when i start animation like rolling or falling coins with different light sourse.

Comment: btw you did a pretty good job anyway.

Comment: i should try more setting on that one i suppose https://i.hizliresim.com/wZERKk.png

Comment: yes so as explained I doubt you can get anything good, I've tried with the medal with the face, which is a rather simple shape but it is still not very good   :/  that said, you should consider using fake 3D + a little bit of real displacement

Comment: by the way fake 3D means it takes the light source into account if that's what you worry about